SSH authentication error after sudo apt upgrade on Ubuntu 24.04: input_userauth_error: bad message during authentication: type 7
After running sudo apt upgrade on my Ubuntu 24.04 system, I started encountering an issue when trying to use Git via SSH. Every time I try to fetch from my Bitbucket repository, I receive the following error:
input_userauth_error: bad message during authentication: type 7
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I can connect without problems from another computer, even using the same private key.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Verified that my SSH keys are correctly added to the SSH agent with ssh-add -l, and my id_ed25519 key is listed.
Tested the connection to Bitbucket with ssh -T git@bitbucket.org, but the same error occurs.
Checked the permissions on my SSH keys (chmod 600 for private keys and chmod 700 for the .ssh folder).
Added the following configuration in my ~/.ssh/config file:

Host bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes


Tried removing all identities with ssh-add -D and re-adding just my id_ed25519 key, but no success.
I’ve also tested with ssh -vvv to get more detailed output, and the error still occurs when the server tries to authenticate.

debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/tmp/ssh-6y3Ocd37580f/agent.127540'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/mike/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Offering public key: /home/mike/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 7
input_userauth_error: bad message during authentication: type 7

I suspect this issue may be related to the latest package updates I installed via sudo apt upgrade because everything was working fine before the upgrade. I'm running OpenSSH_9.6p1 and OpenSSL 3.0.13. Some have suggested adding AllowPKCS12keystoreAutoOpen=no to the SSH config, but it seems my version of OpenSSH doesn't recognize this option.
Has anyone else encountered this issue after running apt upgrade on Ubuntu 24.04? Any guidance on how to resolve this SSH authentication problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
